# How to smoothly load 10 csv files of 500kb each and merge the array with javascript and HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

Given 10 csv files under the same directory, with the same format, but different values. Each file size is about 500kb.

```
   mergedData = []

   for (f in filelist) {
     d3.tsv(f, function(error, data)){

      //Following code cannot work as expected
      mergedData = mergedData.concat(data)

      //then plot with d3js using mergedData
      ...
     }
   }
```

I use these data for visualization with D3, and aware that JavaScript is single threading.

The only solution might be Web Workers, which can run in the backend. But based on
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp

> Since web workers are in external files, they do not have access to
>   the following JavaScript objects:
>
> ```
> The window object
> The document object
> The parent object
> ```

Comment: What do you mean by "Following code cannot work as expected" in your code comment? Do you mean it does not concatenate?

Comment: Define smoothly? Are you attempting to not block the UI? Is processing currently blocking? Processing 5MB of data processing is probably still relatively quick (depending on the resulting processing).

Comment: Do the web workers actually *need* to have access to those objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some libraries around which support asynchronous loading of files. One of those is developed by the maker of D3.js, Mike Bostock. Take a look at his [queue.js](https://github.com/mbostock/queue) which is rather slim and lightweight. If this does not fit your needs, there are other libraries linked to on the queue.js page.